# Oracle query that will list of the database objects referenced by a view

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Is there an Oracle view that will list all of the database objects referenced by the DDL of a given view, procedure, or function?

So if a view is defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW_B AS
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A INNER JOIN VIEW_A
```

running a query on this system view:

```
SELECT REF_OBJECT_NAME, REF_OBJECT_TYPE FROM V$XXX WHERE OBJECT_NAME='VIEW_B'
```

would list something like:

```
REF_OBJECT_NAME  REF_OBJECT_TYPE
TABLE_A          TABLE
VIEW_A           VIEW
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select * from dba_dependencies 
 where owner = 'view owner' 
   and name = 'view name';
```

Comment: If you include the DBA_TABLES view in the query, you can determine row counts: SELECT  REFERENCED_NAME, REFERENCED_TYPE, NUM_ROWS
FROM    DBA_DEPENDENCIES d
INNER JOIN DBA_TABLES t ON d.owner= t.owner
  AND d.referenced_name= t.table_name
WHERE   NAME LIKE '%[view name]%'  --replace [vew name] with actual value
AND     TYPE='VIEW'
ORDER BY REFERENCED_NAME